# Keep tcp connection open using python3.4's xmlrpc.server

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, xml-rpc

I have a server-client application using xmlrpc.server and xmlrpc.client where the clients request data from the server. As the server only returns this data once certain conditions are met, the clients make the same call over and over again, and currently the tcp connection is re-initiated with each call. This creates a noticeable delay.

I have a fixed number of clients that connect to the server at the beginning of the application and shutdown when the whole application is finished.

I tried to google about keeping the TCP connection open, but all I could find either talked about xmlrpclib or did not apply to the python version.

Client-side code:

```
import xmlrpc.client as xc
server =  xc.ServerProxy(host_IP,8000)

var = False
while type(var)==bool:
    var = server.pull_update() 
    # this returns "False" while the server determines the conditions 
    # for the client to receive the update aren't met; and the update 
    # once the conditions are met
```

Server-side, I am extending  xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCServer with the default xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler. The function in question is:

```
def export_pull_update(self):
    if condition:
        return self.var
    else:
        return False
```

Is there a way to get xmlrpc.server to keep the connection alive between calls for the server?
Or should I go the route of using ThreadingMixIn and not completing the client-request until the condition is met?